# Display data at index between two models or more in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, psql

Currently, I have two tables `countries` and `users`

schema for `countries` something like this,

- id
- country_code
- name

and for `users` table,

- id
- name
- born_country_id
- live_at_country_id

so for `users/index.html.erb` instead showing born_at_id or live_at_id that I've got from country table id, I wanna show the name for that country.

I have try and search quite lot articles regarding this matter, but none of it works for me.

For my table do I need to put references during migrations for users table or is it enough just using `has_one`, many and belongs_to and how to display the data in index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following associations in you models,

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :born_country, foreign_key: :born_country_id, class_name: 'Country'
  belongs_to :live_at_country, foreign_key: :live_at_country_id, class_name: 'Country'

  delegate :name, to: :born_country, prefix: true
  delegate :name, to: :lived_at_country, prefix: true 
end
```

country.rb

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :born_users, foreign_key: :born_country_id, class_name: 'User' 
  has_many :live_at_users, foreign_key: :live_at_country_id, class_name: 'User'
end
```

You can check it in below manner,

```
@users = User.includes(:born_country, :lived_at_country).each do |user|
  puts user.born_at_country_name
  puts user.lived_at_country_name
end
```

Comment: first of all thanks for your quick respond, currently for index.html.erb <%= user. name %> .. how to fetch the data?

Comment: Have associations I defined & pass `User.includes(:born_country, :lived_at_country)` through `index` action.  You can get `<%= user.born_at_country_name` in index page

Comment: undefined method `delegates', do i need to require anything?

Comment: @DanielSufian use `delegate`

Comment: wow. its working, any articles can explain how this things work if you dont mind? anyway thanks a lot @ray

Comment: @DanielSufian You must read [ActiveRecord Association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) & [Rails Delegate](https://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) in detail & practice in daily life